# How can i merge multiple functions on a single button on javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to use "confirm password form" (it is at bootstrap - modal) nested on a site tour step. Actually i have just did it. But the problem is i cant merge 2 different functions on one button which "confirms password" and the "next" step.

The purpose of merging these functions:
When a user confirms password normally closes the modal box and works fine thanks to this code below.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#basicModal").modal();

     $(".update-password").click(function(){

      var new_password = $("#new-password").val();
      var confirm_password = $("#confirm-password").val();

      if(new_password==""){
          $("#new-password").focus();
          return;
      }

      if(confirm_password==""){
          $("#confirm-password").focus();
          return;
      }
  });

  setTimeout(function(){
      $("#basicModal").modal('hide');
  },25000);

  $("#upd-btn").click(function(){
      $("#basicModal").modal();
  });
})
```

But it shouldnt close anymore and continue to next step.. So i try to merge them but i dont have enough code experience to solve this by myself.. so i need you to support me on this problem guys.. while you are reading i ll keep up to try.. thank you all..

related code of the "button" and the "next" link is here below

```
<div class="" id="step-id-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create your password pls.</h4>
            </div>
             <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You should fill the field with password </p>


                <p><input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="new-password" required placeholder="Yeni Şife.." name="new-password" /></p>
                <p><input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="confirm-password" required placeholder="Repeat you password pls.." name="confirm-password" /></p>
                <?php if($flag){ ?>
                <div style="padding:5px 10px; color:#fff; background:#F00">Passwords are unmatched, refill the form please</div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

               **<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary update-password">Confirm your password</button>**

        </div></form>  

              **<a href="#" data-powertour-action="next" style="float:right">Next step</a>**
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the one function call the other, or create a 3rd function that calls both and call that 3rd function with the button.

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for quick reply :) unfortunately i have no idea about js .. just editing values pasting different variations to wish it works :/

Comment: ok, what are the 2 different functions called that you want to do?  are they in the code you pasted?

Comment: there is a class in button "update-password" which i believe functions the code to confirms psw and closes the modal.. but when i add data-powertour-action="next" to button .. this time next function works but "update-password"